# Dynamic GridVIew ItemClick not working in xamarin android

Tags: c#, android, gridview, xamarin, xamarin.android

I crated a dynamic GridView which having a custom  Adapterclass. Now i try to get the position and position name of click at GridView.
For that i used ItemClick, Problem is that its not working.

Here is my code.

This is my custom Adapter

```
using System;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.App;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Graphics;
using System.Net;
using Square.Picasso;
using Android.Util;

namespace AMUSEAndroid
{
public class GridViewAdapter : BaseAdapter<ImageItem> 
{
    Activity context;
    List<ImageItem> items;

    public GridViewAdapter (Activity context, List<ImageItem> gridViewtems)
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = gridViewtems;
    }

    public override int Count {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }

    public override ImageItem this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override long GetItemId (int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup     parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        var item = items[position];
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.player_grid_item, null);
        ImageView imgIcon =  view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.img_play_bg);//.SetImageBitmap (gridViewtems[position]);
        view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.music_text).Text = item.Heading;

        /*imgIcon.Click += delegate(object sender, EventArgs e) {
            Toast.MakeText (context, "Click"+position, ToastLength.Short).Show ();

            Log.Info("BIKAHS","click at"+position);
        };*/
        /*var imageBitmap = GetImageBitmapFromUrl(item.ImageResourceId);
        imgIcon.SetImageBitmap(imageBitmap);*/



        Picasso.With(context)
            .Load(item.ImageResourceId)
            //.Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.place_holder)
            .Into(imgIcon);
        return view;

    }

    void ImgIcon_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Toast.MakeText (context, "Click"+position, ToastLength.Short).Show ();
    }


}
```

}

ItemCLick is working when i don't use the custom adapter clase.

What to do.. Any idea or reference. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Try this you need to register the **click event***

```
public override View GetView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup     parent)
        {
            View view = convertView;
            var item = items[position];
            if (view == null)
                view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.player_grid_item, null);
            ImageView imgIcon =  view.FindViewById<ImageView> (Resource.Id.img_play_bg);//.SetImageBitmap (gridViewtems[position]);
            view.FindViewById<TextView> (Resource.Id.music_text).Text = item.Heading;

                     //register the click event
                     imgIcon.Click+=ImgIcon_Click 


            Picasso.With(context)
                .Load(item.ImageResourceId)
                //.Placeholder(Resource.Drawable.place_holder)
                .Into(imgIcon);
            return view;

        }

        void ImgIcon_Click (object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           var name=items[e.postion].heading;
        }
```

Comment: Yeah . I used that , Here i get only the position , But i need position and position name also. How do i get this..?

Comment: Just Use you collection ITEMS LIKE ,,,Your list ITEMS[POSTION].Heading